# Webmatrix 2 Beta and Visual Studio 10 Issue

Tags: webmatrix

I just downloaded the Webmatrix 2 Prerelease Beta-

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=webmatrix&prerelease=true

I played around and made a database with some tables.  Then I went to open up Visual Studio 2010 and I was prompted to install some missing components.  That all went well except when the plaform installer tried to install ASP Razor 2 Syntax for Visual Studio.  I get the following error-

"The product you are trying to install is not supported on your operating system. Click here for more information."

I click, nothing useful comes up.  Has anyone seen this and know a solution? Or am I just a little too early and have to wait?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sadly, this same issue appears to be present in Visual Studio 11 Beta as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in pre-release software. Could you report it here?

https://connect.microsoft.com/webmatrix/Feedback

Comment: @infocyde Have you reported this issue? If so, post a link to that issue here for others running into the same problem to vote up as well.

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem, I created a [Microsoft Connect feedback page](https://connect.microsoft.com/webmatrix/feedback/details/695332/visual-studio-launch-issue) for it. Feel free to go vote up the issue.

Comment: The link is not working now, gives ` The system has encountered an unexpected error. We apologize for the inconvenience. The issue will be addressed as quickly as possible.` So sad it is when error-reporting page gives an error.